# Division in Apex, explain

Tags: apex, decimal

```
Integer a = totalRecords.size(); //1250
decimal b = 400;

integer block = a/b;  //3
```

The actual result of 1250/400 is 3.125.  Because I used integer block, I get 3 as answer.  Instead of that if I use

```
decimal block = a/b;  

I get the result as 3.125
```

But what I want is, if the result is not perfect number (anything with decimals, like 3.125), I want it to be shown as 4 (increment by 1).  If its perfect division, then I want to leave it as it it.

How to achieve this? Please let me know.

Another example:

```
1303/5 = 260.6, I want the result to be 261
1300/5 = 260.  I want 260 only.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm#apex_System_Decimal_round_2) for Decimal class

in order to achieve what you want you need to round your result up:

```
Decimal block = a/b;
Integer roundedBlock = block.round(System.RoundingMode.UP));
```

UPDATE: I have suggested you use RoundingMode.UP based on your examples, however you should also consider using RoundMode.CEILING (or Math.ceil() as suggested by @MLucci) - difference between the two is around behaviour with negative numbers.

Comment: As well as Math.ceil(a / b) (which gives back a Decimal/Double instead, even though rounded to Integer). See https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_math.htm#apex_System_Math_ceil

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code : -
The solution is to explicitly convert one of the values in the division expression to a Double before the division operation is performed.

```java
Integer x = 5;
Integer y = 2;
Double d = ((Double) x) / y;
```

In this case the Integer x is casted to a Double and the Integer y is promoted to a Double for the duration of the calculation, so that a Double division can be performed. The result is 2.5.

Comment: short and very helpful answer, thank you!